# Don't show other validation messages without presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Right now, I have a `User` model with a `username` field that's being validated by:

```
validates :username, 
    :presence => true,
    :length => { :in => 3..60 }, 
    :format => { :with => /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_ ]+$/ }
```

How can I hide the `:length` and `:format` validation errors if `:presence` is not met?

Answer (score 4):

Try :allow_blank => true in 2nd and 3rd validations.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do like this:

```
validates :username, 
  :presence => true,
  :length => { :in => 3..60, :allow_nil => true }, 
  :format => { :with => /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_ ]+$/, :allow_nil => true }
```

It will not care about length and format validations when username is not set, but it will work fine with at least one character typed.